# How to write SQL JOIN Query for get results when one table id existing in more than one columns in other table

Tags: sql

I have two tables 'users' and 'jobs'. According to this DB design 'users' and 'jobs' table look as following;

**Table name: users**

```
id | first_name | last_name  
1  | John       | Smith  
2  | Lee        | Smith  
3  | Max        | Smith
```

**Table name: jobs**

```
id | job_name | assign_to_1 | assign_to_2 | assign_to_3
1  | Plumbing | 1           |   2         | 3
```

I want to get all jobs with assign names, I wrote query like this,

```
SELECT 
jobs.job_name,
jobs.assign_to_1,
jobs.assign_to_2,
jobs.assign_to_3
FROM jobs
JOIN users ON users.id IN (jobs.assign_to_1,jobs.assign_to_2, jobs.assign_to_3)
```

Someone please explain how to get assign_to_1 user's name, assign_to_2 user's name,
assign_to_3 user's name instead of user's ids.

Comment: I'd redesign jobs table. Have one row per assign_to.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks for the comment, but I don't have permission to redesign tables

Comment: With the current table design you have to join users 3 times. (I.e. once per assign_to value.)

Comment: first/last name? (desired output..would be nice if you add it)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? You should always tag SQL questions with the DBMS you want an answer for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use multiple joins and aliases

this code should work:

```
select j.job_name, u1.name as emp1, u2.name as em2, u3.name as emp3 
         from jobs j join users as u1 on j.assign_to_1=u1.id 
                     join users as u2 on j.assign_to_2=u2.id 
                     join users as u3 on j.assign_to_3=u3.id
```

I assume you just need job name and each employee first name (editing is easy if you need surnames)

In any case I advise you to redesign the table, because with current configuration you have up to 3 emp and future you have to alter the table to add new emp to same job.

I'll do like this (relational notation)

```
EMP(first_name, last_name, emp_id)
job(name, job_id) 
work(emp_id,job_id) fk job_id ref. job, emp_id ref. emp
```

with this arrangement you can add an arbitrary number of workers to each job and also querying is cheap because of only 2 joins

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

**Table name: users**

```
id | first_name | last_name  
1  | John       | Smith  
2  | Lee        | Smith  
3  | Max        | Smith
```

**Table name: jobs**

```
id | job_name 
1  | Plumbing
```

**Table name: job_users**

```
job_id | user_id | priority
1      | 1       | 1 
1      | 2       | 2
1      | 3       | 3
```

and then query it like this:

```
SELECT
  jobs.id, job_name, concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS assignee, priority 
FROM
  (jobs LEFT JOIN job_users on jobs.id = job_id) INNER JOIN users ON user_id = users.id
```

Comment: I agree with&like your re-modelling (whether this is an option??), but would add an additional "prio" or "index" column (to M-to-N table), to also depict the "order of assignees".

Answer (score 1):

Change **"assign_to_1_user, assign_to_2_user, assign_to_3_user"** name as per your requirement.
Use different Joins of **users table** with different Alis.

```
SELECT 
    jb.job_name,
    CONCAT(user1.first_name, ' ', user1.last_name) AS assign_to_1_user,
    CONCAT(user2.first_name, ' ', user2.last_name) AS assign_to_2_user,
    CONCAT(user3.first_name, ' ', user3.last_name) AS assign_to_3_user
    FROM jobs as jb
    INNER JOIN users user1 ON user1.id = jb.assign_to_1
    INNER JOIN users user2 ON user2.id = jb.assign_to_2
    INNER JOIN users user3 ON user3.id = jb.assign_to_3
```